# Bootstrap expect=1 in consul results in weird behavior in cluster

Tags: consul

Trying to launch a cluster of nodes one at a time, and I'm a bit confused about the bootstrap-expect value.

The way it is set up is that consul is launched with bootstrap-expect, then after it starts `consul join` is ran

Currently, the deployment sets bootstrap-expect have it set to the number of nodes in the cluster, and a leader is elected after that number.

However, when bootstrap-expect is set to 1 (thought process is so we can have a cluster without waiting for all the nodes), something strange happens.

So first, each node thinks it is the leader - which is expected since bootstrap-expect is set to 1. But after doing consul join to each other, a new cluster leader isn't elected - what happens is strange - each node in the cluster still thinks itself as a cluster leader.

Why don't the nodes, when joining a cluster, elect a new leader? Or at least respect the prexisting leader?

Answer (score 2):

This is condition called [Split Brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-brain_%28computing%29) that you've "intentionally" created. Each server think's it's the leader and has it's own version of the log and each of these versions are not reconcilable with each other. Split Brain is famously hard to recover from. Since the Servers can not agree on what the Cluster State should be, they can't decide who the new leader should be, and they continue without a successful election. You can read up on [Raft](https://ramcloud.stanford.edu/wiki/download/attachments/11370504/raft.pdf) to learn more about why.

Comment: I expect there should be a manual command from admin to force some of servers to join other server as not a leader.